# Using inherited clases on Entity Framework for ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I  have two Entities, User and Users_Participant : User, Which participate in the ParticipantUser relationship. User has {Id, User_Name, User_Pass, UserTypeType_Id (foreign key)}, and Users_Participant has First_Name, Last_Name, Mail, Phone, Id and User_Id, that would count as a Foreign Key towards User.

Problem is, when I try to insert a Participant, it throws me this error: 
"Entities in 'EMSModelContainer.Users' participate in the 'ParticipantUser' relationship. 0 related 'Participant' were found. 1 'Participant' is expected." I'm using the scaffolded code that MVC adds through Razor

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Participant participant)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Users.AddObject(participant);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.UserTypeType_Id = new SelectList(db.UserTypes, "Type_Id", "Description", participant.UserTypeType_Id);
        return View(participant);
    }
```

Is there any way to include User data inside the submit procedure?

[image: My Model depiction]

Comment: Are you using fluent? If so what does your mapping look like? If not can we see the models in question?

Comment: Yes, lots of different ways inheritance can be implemented.  Table per type, per concrete class, etc.  So will need to see models+mapping.

Comment: There, I added the classes

Comment: One guess is that you may need to use `db.Participants.Add` instead of `db.Users.Add` to save the instance in order to have EF save it correctly.